# Logical operator manipulation

Tags: websphere, logic

I am working on IBM eXtreme scale that doesn't readily support the OR logical operator but supports AND. So my question is, Is their a way to achieve a OR using AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) apply here.  So, instead of

```
A OR B
```

...test if

```
NOT(NOT(A) AND NOT(B))
```